# Exporting 15000x voucher codes made with Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to export a voucher code for a flyer with Excel. I want to create 15000 rows with random voucher codes. So far I have made below, but how can I make it create 15000 voucher codes for each row?

Thanks a lot.

```
import random
import string
import pandas as pd

def random_string_generator(str_size, allowed_chars):
    return ''.join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for x in range(str_size))

chars = string.ascii_uppercase
size = 5

for i in range(15000):
    print (random_string_generator(size, chars)+"-"+random_string_generator(size, chars)+"-"+random_string_generator(size, chars)+"-"+random_string_generator(size, chars)+"-"+random_string_generator(size, chars))
```

Comment: What have you tried? For example, `for i in range(1500):` or something similar?

Comment: Hey, yes but it is not random when I do that.. It will print the same code

Comment: I also tried with a function now, but that outputs not even the voucher code. Output is 10 times the same e.g. <function vouchercodefc at 0x00000205DBC03310>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your original code with a few tweaks:

```py
import random
import string

chars = string.ascii_uppercase
amount_of_vouchers = 10
segments_per_voucher = 5
chars_per_segment = 5

def random_string_generator(allowed_chars, str_size):
    return ''.join(random.choices(allowed_chars, k=str_size))

vouchers = []
for i in range(amount_of_vouchers):    
    voucher = [random_string_generator(chars, chars_per_segment) for j in range(segments_per_voucher)]
    vouchers.append('-'.join(voucher))
    
print('\n'.join(vouchers))
```

What I've done:

1. Instead of concatenating the function calls on one line, I've changed this to a loop. This is easier to read, easier to change and shorter.
2. Added a loop around the code generation, so that we can create multiple vouchers
3. Vouchers are stored in the imaginatively named `vouchers` array.
4. Changed `random.choice` to `random.choices`, which allows us to generate the entire segment at once, rather than per character.

Example output:

```
RIRSE-BURXY-NTBFP-VZTBC-LNQYD
OWTSZ-AIUPS-POXMW-PQXJY-DUXUE
BFDJI-ASLPZ-XIRKR-ZKVLB-YGRCA
SQTHJ-DYJYL-IZQFD-EFBJO-OWPHO
OWPWW-PJGNY-BOCZM-ANNLJ-CFXKY
NHQUN-MMBQB-KHLYL-ZQVTD-TDUQC
MNOYT-WAVWV-QSUND-RYKHB-TNUCF
OAHOR-DPJFN-RQYHE-GUSVF-CPCBF
OFNHT-LCARH-EZDWT-YRLLI-IWJZW
NXLKI-GCJDM-QZGPU-MIZCC-XSOQD
```

Comment: Wow! That's an awesome solution!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added a fourth tweak, which makes the random string generation a bit simpler.

Comment: Try with double backslashes, like so: `df.to_excel(excel_writer = "C:\\Temp\\SO\\Vouchers.xlsx")` that works correctly for me. Alternatively you could just save it to a CSV file with one voucher per row (same as the way it's printed). That'll open very easily in Excel.

Comment: I fixed it with putting r in front of the string :) Guess it does the same as \\

Comment: Do you know how I can make it print per row instead of per column?

Comment: Nvm :) fixed it in Excel. Thank you so much for helping man!

Comment: That's right about the `r` - it treats a backslash as just another character. Normally a backslash has a special meaning in strings (`\n` = new line, `\t` = tab, etc), but we can get around that by just putting two backslashes, which python interprets as one non-special backslash.

Comment: or to put it another way: these will print the same thing: `print(r"ab\cd")` `print("ab\\cd")`